# Dyanamic tabs creation with dynamic view pager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe

I want to create a dynamic swipe able tab layout. I am able to create dynamic number of tabs, but i am not able to figure out how to create fragments dynamically for corresponding tab and also views inside each fragment.